# How do I edit a curve without having to change any origins to the curved meshes?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I have a curve that representates an off-ramp. Parented to the curve is two meshes, roadway and inner lines.

The modifier to the two meshes are an array to fit curve and curve modifier to deform along X axis.

https://i.imgur.com/W0ePI65.mp4

How do I edit a curve without having to set the origin of meshes that uses the curve each time?

Comment: please provide your blend file. you can check whether you have non applied scale/rotation on your curve.

Comment: The solution is to **not use the meshes as children of the curve**.